# Interval of convergence $\sum_1^\infty \frac{2^n}{3n}(x+3)^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

$$\sum_1^\infty \frac{2^n}{3n}(x+3)^n$$

I do the ratio test to find the radius.

$$\frac{2^{n+1}}{3(n+1)}(x+3)^{n+1} *\frac{3n}{2^n (x+3)^n}$$

This should reduce down to $2|x+6|< 1$

This is wrong though, where did I go wrong?

Comment: You should divide the terms instead of multiplying them.

Comment: I did do that. I will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let 
$$u_n=\frac{2^n}{3n}(x+3)^n$$
then by the ratio test:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}=2|x+3|<1\iff-\frac{7}{2} <x<-\frac{5}{2}$$
we can verify that the series is convergent at $x=-\frac{7}{2}$ (alternating series) so the interval of convergence is $[-\frac{7}{2},-\frac{5}{2})$.

Comment: Where do you get 3? I get 6.

Comment: Notice to find $u_{n+1}$ just replace $n$ by $n+1$ in $u_n$.

Comment: The 3n is a linear term and doesn not "contribute" in ratiotest. When you consider the term (2x+6)^n by the rule of exponents, the then the by Sami states inequality becomes obvious, because by ratiotest, the exponent "drops". This reasoning is not "clean" to put on a quiz, nevertheless, it is true here.